# Select data where the range between two different fields contains a given number

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to make a find query on my database for documents that have an input value between or equal to these 2 fields, `LOC_CEP_INI` and `LOC_CEP_FIM`

Example: user input a number to the system with value : 69923994, then I use this input to search my database for all documents that have this value between the range of the fields `LOC_CEP_INI` and `LOC_CEP_FIM`.

One of my documents (in this example this document is selected by the query because the input is inside the range):

```
 {
   "_id" : ObjectId("570d57de457405a61b183ac6"),
   "LOC_CEP_FIM" : 69923999, //this field is number
   "LOC_CEP_INI" : 69900001, // this field is number
   "LOC_NO" : "RIO BRANCO",
   "LOC_NU" : "00000016",
   "MUN_NU" : "1200401",
   "UFE_SG" : "AC",
   "create_date" : ISODate("2016-04-12T20:17:34.397Z"),
   "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
db.collection.find( { field: { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } } );
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/
 refer this mongo provide range facility with $gt  and $lt .

Answer (score 3):

You have to invert your field names and query value.

```
db.zipcodes.find({
    LOC_CEP_INI: {$gte: 69923997},
    LOC_CEP_FIM: {$lte: 69923997}
});
```

For your query example to work, you would need your documents to hold an `array` property, and that each item in this prop hold a `69923997` prop. Mongo would then check that this `69923997` prop has a value that is both between `"LOC_CEP_INI"` and `"LOC_CEP_FIM"` for each item in your `array` prop.

Also I'm not sure whether you want `LOC_CEP_INI <= 69923997 <= LOC_CEP_FIM` or the contrary, so you might need to switch the `$gte` and `$lte` conditions.

Comment: Humm and if i dont have a array property?

Comment: then you just write the code example i gave. What i meant is that if you write `db.zipcodes.find({array: ...})`, mongo will try to match your condition on an `array` prop of your documents. If they don't have one, just skip it, and write the `$elemMatch` condition directly

Comment: #VonD i tried like you said with your code but i receive a error     Error: error: {
 "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $elemMatch",
 "code" : 2
}

Comment: tried with db.zipcodes.find({
    $elemMatch: {
        LOC_CEP_INI: {$gte: 69923997},
        LOC_CEP_FIM: {$lte: 69923997}
    }
});

Comment: @michelpm1 sorry, i got confused with this `array` thing. I've edited my answer. `$elemMatch` is useful if one of your props is an array. Let's say your documents as an `items` props and that each item has the `LOC_CEP_INI ` and `LOC_CEP_FIM ` props, then you would write `{items: {$elemMatch: { LOC_CEP_INI: {$gte: 69923997}, LOC_CEP_FIM: {$lte: 69923997} }}}`

Answer (score 0):

> db.zipcodes.find( {
>       "LOC_CEP_INI": { "$lte": 69900002 }, 
>       "LOC_CEP_FIM": { "$gte": 69900002 }  })

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic use it as per the need:

```
 Userdb.aggregate([
    { "$match": { _id: ObjectId(session._id)}},
    { $project: {
        checkout_list: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$checkout_list",
                as: "checkout_list",
                cond: {
                    $and: [
                        { $gte: [ "$$checkout_list.createdAt", new Date(date1) ] },
                        { $lt: [ "$$checkout_list.createdAt", new Date(date2) ] }
                    ]
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Here i use filter, because of some reason data query on nested data is not gets succeed in mongodb