# translating a small javascript expression to mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi i'm trying to translate this javascript expression with mongo:

```
db.zipcodes.find( { $where: "69900002 >= obj.LOC_CEP_INI && 69900002 <= obj.LOC_CEP_FIM" } );
```

To a mongo query. I need that because the javascript is not performatic for query big data.

What i need is search objects where the field LOC_CEP_INI is bigger or equal to 69900002 and LOC_CEP_FIM is equal or smaller than LOC_CEP_INI
Thanks!

OUTPUT Example (69900002 is bigger than LOC_CEP_INI and 69900002 is smaller than 69900002:

```
 {
"create_date": "2016-04-12T20:17:34.397Z",
 "__v": 0,
"UFE_SG": "AC",
"MUN_NU": "1200401",
"LOC_NU": "00000016",
"LOC_NO": "RIO BRANCO",
"LOC_CEP_INI": 69900001,
"LOC_CEP_FIM": 69923999,
"_id": "570d57de457405a61b183ac6"
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @user3100115 i m trying to search objects where the field LOC_CEP_INI is bigger or equal to 69900002 and LOC_CEP_FIM is equal or smaller than LOC_CEP_INI

Comment: Please post sample document with the expected output.

Comment: i posted @user3100115

Comment: Isn't this the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583399/mongo-shell-query-to-select-data-between-a-range-of-two-diferent-fields)?

Comment: No, now i want only to translate the javascript expression

Comment: @michelpm1 How is it functionally any different though? The answers are the same for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) and the [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) query operators to select those document where "LOC_CEP_INI" is lower than `69900002` and "LOC_CEP_FIM" is greater than `69900002`.

```js
db.zipcodes.find( {  
    "LOC_CEP_INI": { "$lte": 69900002 }, 
    "LOC_CEP_FIM": { "$gte": 69900002 } 
})
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!!